# What does the simpl tactic do in COQ

Tags: coq

I am wondering how the `simpl` tactic works in COQ.
Assume the following Lemma:

```
Parameter n:nat. 
Lemma test: S n + 0 = S (n+0).
```

Now, the `simpl.` tactic produces

```
S (n + 0) = S (n + 0)
```

My understanding is that `simpl` performs a sequence of 
`cbv beta, delta, iota` conversions.
I tried that, but could not manage to get the same result as `simpl`. The basic problem is that after a `cbv delta` expansion, the `plus` term keeps expanded. How can I de-expand it, i.e. re-substitute the `plus` name for the expanded definition?
Or, can anyone show me how I can get the effect of `simpl` by manually performing more elementary tactics?

Comment: I advise you crawl into Coq's ML archive (Coq-Club). This subject is non-trivial and arise periodically. You should find what your are looking for there.

Comment: Did anybody get a link for this?

Comment: Here's a partial explanation: https://gitter.im/coq/coq?at=5a22a9f171ad3f873658ab1c

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe it possible to emulate the `simpl` tactic using only `cbv`, because indeed `cbv delta` does not let you choose which occurences to replace, while `simpl` only performs delta-reduction when it leads to a iota step. (cf. https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.simpl)

So, even if informally we can say that `simpl` performs such a sequence of calls, it seems like it has access to a lower-level way of performing those reductions than what the `cbv` tactic exposes.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How could one emulate the statement above with some elementary tactics? Or stated in another way, where do I get more information, how "simpl" works?

Comment: simpl is magic.  You can "emulate" it with `change` via `let x := (magically get the result of simpl) in change x`, if you can magically get the result of simpl.  In fact, simpl is so much magic that the devs implemented a couple of years ago cbn, which is supposed to be a more "well-behaved" version of simpl, but still have not worked out all the kinks and disagreements between the two tactics.  The main magic that simpl does, as you noted, is fixpoint refolding.  How it decides which fixpoints to refold is quite complicated.